# Flutter QR how to pass QR data to the next screen

Tags: flutter

How do I make it so when the user scan a QR code, the result will then be passed to the next screen.

Here is my code so far,

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) => SafeArea(
child: Scaffold(
  body: Stack(
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      buildQrView(context),
      Positioned(top: 10, child: buildControlButtons()),
      Positioned(bottom: 30, child: buildResult()),
    ],
  ),
),
```

The buildResult is this

```
Widget buildResult() => Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: Colors.white24),
child: Text(
    barcode != null ? _dataFetch() : 'Scan a code!',
    maxLines: 3,
),
```

Then the function _dataFetch is as below

```
  _dataFetch() async {
if (barcode == null) {
  print('error');
} else {
  var route = new MaterialPageRoute(
      builder: (BuildContext context) =>
      new TransferProcessQR(
          value: PassdataQR(
            email: barcode!.code.toString(),
          )
      )
  );
  Navigator.of(context).push(route);
}
```

I have another class for PassdataQR but its pretty self explanatory. With this code everytime I run it will give me an error

> The following _TypeError was thrown building QRScanPage(dirty, dependencies: [MediaQuery], state: _QRScanPageState#720ae):
> type 'Future' is not a subtype of type 'String'

and the Navigator functions will be messed up.

Is there another approach I can do, so after a QR code is scanned, the result will be passed to the next screen without errors?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that your `_dataFetch` method returns a futureand in your `buildResult` method you're using it like so:

```
Text(
    barcode != null ? _dataFetch() : 'Scan a code!',
    maxLines: 3,
)
```

You can use a futurebuilder to retrieve the async data:

```
Widget buildResult() => Container(
padding: EdgeInsets.all(12),
decoration: BoxDecoration(
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8), color: Colors.white24),
child: FutureBuilder<string>(
  future: _dataFetch,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.HasData) {
      return Text(snapshot.data, maxLines: 3);
    } else return Text('Scan a code!', maxLines: 3);
  },
 ),
);
```

Comment: Yep it doesn' work. It displays error: Unexpected text 'await'. How do I make the future builder?

Comment: I updated the answer to use a futurebuilder, I hope the code works, since I didn't code it in an editor.

Comment: It displays me this error [link](https://imgur.com/a/oIahbb1)

Comment: I just realised that you need to change your code completly. You're trying to change the page if a QR code was scanned, but you're doing the logic in a Text widget. You could actually just write Text('Scan a code!', maxLines: 3) and have a listener somewhere that gets notified if a barcode was scanned and then navigates to a new page...

Comment: I think so, I am kind of stuck with this right now. Any chance you can direct me on how to do that?

Comment: I don't know enough of your code, but basically you could use a provider https://pub.dev/packages/provider and put your logic in there. If you need more help you could upload your code to a repository or something similar

Comment: Here's an upload for the codes [link](https://github.com/fadelazhar/mbpayment.git).

Answer (score 0):

According to your [repository](https://github.com/fadelazhar/mbpayment/blob/main/lib/screens/QR%20Scanner/qr_scan.dart) you could just modify line 150:

```
 controller.scannedDataStream
        .listen((barcode) => {
  setState(() => this.barcode = barcode));

  Get.to(new TransferProcessQR(
          value: PassdataQR(
            email: barcode!.code.toString(),
          )
      ));
}
```

Notice that in order for this to work you'll have to use the [Get Package Route Management](https://pub.dev/packages/get#route-management) to navigate to another page. That's because you don't have access to the build context in this code snipped. Normally you would call `Navigator.of(context).push(...)` but that's not possible without a build context.

Comment: After using this code, every time I open the QR scanner it is now just white with error saying. > The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  QRView-[GlobalKey#0c1a3 QR] QRView:file:///C:/Users/user/AndroidStudioProjects/mbpayment/lib/screens/QR%20Scanner/qr_scan.dart:135:47